# Parallax backgrond fixed bug in chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

When I give my class a background fixed for the parallax it works smooth and nice in FireFox.
Only in Chrome and Safari the background is bugged, wont scroll nice and a color is overlayed.

The link to the site is : http://www.autogigant.nl
If tried many options but I cant get it fixed.

Someone knows this problem?

Comment: Someone knows an answers for this?

Comment: Whatever that site was, it's no longer available.

Comment: anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove background-position: fixed !important on line 254 in style.css ...

Comment: have you traied? Solved?

Comment: Hi, I already tried that but Its not working.
Currently I deleted the !important

Comment: On Chrome it's working fine witout (position: fixed)...also on Opera and Firefox... i think your problem is the width of the device... try to set somthing like: background-size: 200%;

Comment: If I remove the position:fixed and give it a background-size of 200% or even more. I get a black/gray bar in the top of the background which is about 30px.

Comment: So, the problem is the js. And device width/height relationship ...so the best to do is: change js or change image ratio...

Comment: I dont think thats the problem, the div .parallax {} is overlaying  the .parallax-bg {} plus the background is not scrolling good.